# Baking normal from high poly to low poly

Tags: baking

I sculpted a high res model, and retopologized a low res model. I want to bake the normal from the high res to the low res, so i use smart UV project to unwrap the high res and the retopologized low res > placed them at the same position > created an image texture > ticked selected to active and then bake. After baking, i plug the normal into the principled BSDF's normal input, but the result seems weird.

Firstly, is the my flow correct? I am following the steps from the video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw&t=5s

But since it is a character, i not sure is the same flow can be applied.

Besides, the normal map is having some parts shows as green and orange. I tried to increase the ray distance but it does not work also. May i know any possible fixes?

[image]

**Thank you so much for helping :D**

Comment: On the Image Texture the Color Space must be Non-Color instead of sRGB. I don't know why it is greyed out (may be you plugged it in before baking). Try to save the normal map then load it again.

Comment: Yea i also not sure why, but i try to create a new image texture, set it to non color and bake it again then it works abit better. But may i know is it a correct way to directly baked a triangulated high res model into a low retopologized mesh?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The topolgy doesn't count, just the shape.